# "is one of degree" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The sentence is in Chapter two of Rebecca Solnit's Men Explain Things to Me.

> “Women in the online gaming communit have been harassed, threatened,
>   and driven out. Anita Sarkeesian, a feminist media critic who
>   documented such incidents, received support for her work, but also, in
>   the words of a journalist, 'another wave of really aggressive, you
>   know, violent personal threats, her accounts attempted to be hacked.
>   And one man in Ontario took the step of making an online video game
>   where you could punch Anita's image on the screen. And if you punched
>   it multiple times, bruises and cuts would appear on her image.' The
>   difference between these online gamers and the Taliban men who, last
>   October, tried to murder fourteen-year-old Malala Yousafzai for
>   speaking out about the right of Pakistani women to education **is one of
>   degree**. Both are trying to silence and punish women for claiming
>   voice, power, and the right to participate.”

I think that it meant that the two incidents are **the same**?

But, I'm not sure, please provide me with a definition.

Comment: My take is: The difference … is one [of degree].  In other words, their degrees are different.  But I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: It just means the difference between online gamers and repressive Taliban men isn't something "absolute" (like the difference between *black* and *white*). They're just different points on a "continuum" (as, say, ***lighter** grey* and ***darker** grey*).

Answer (score 4):

The phrase you have highlighted is part of a very long sentence with various parenthetic statements. It might help to cut it down a bit:

> The difference between these online gamers and the Taliban men <s>who, last October, tried to murder fourteen-year-old Malala Yousafzai for speaking out about the right of Pakistani women to education</s> is one of degree.

It is saying the *difference* between these two groups of men is one of degree.

"Degree" means the *amount, level, or extent* to which something happens or is present.

So, what this means is that the difference in behaviour between these two groups of men being discussed is about the *level* of their behaviour, not the *type*. They both apparently threatened women, but one to a far greater degree than the other.